# Template 10's Navigation Value property

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I see the property **Value** in relation to NavigationService in Template 10.  what is special about this property? How should it used? No doc on this topic and some one may help me explain?

Comment: Where do you see this Value property? What version are you using?  It's not used, at any rate.

Comment: I am currently using Template 10 and I dont see any Value property on NavigationService. Can you provide some example or something? Also whiich version of Template10 are you using?

Comment: I think I can understand a bit now but not fully (and when I do I will answer it). The Value prop appears in many of the samples. I think navigation "suspension state" uses a property by the name Value and also if you have a property Value in view-model it copies value to it. It seems a systematic way to manage suspended navigation state but sadly the doc does not say anything on this. Will keep digging and hopefully someone will come up with a definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. Okay, so I took the time to look into what you are asking about. I'm telling you, man, there just isn't a `Value` property in the Template 10 Navigation Service. I've included a class diagram from the framework's source so show you.

[image]

If instead you mean the Suspension State `Dictionary` passed to the OnNavigatedTo() and OnNavigatedFrom() methods implemented by `INavigable`, which has a `Value` property, this this is simply a property bag used by you to save values when you Suspend and to fetch values when you Restore. One important aside with this dictionary is that it is cleared when the user navigates to a page with the same type, and it is only persisted when your app is terminated while suspended. During normal Suspend/Resume, the fast-switching is automatic and though OnNavigatedFrom() is called, OnNavigatedTo() is never called. Your app is simply restored from memory automatically without needing your intervention. Should you need to intervene (music apps want this capability) the BootStrapper's OnResume override can catch this operation and call out to your view-model or music service.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. That explains everything and now I can follow.